# Have stick-breaking priors with non-iid atoms been considered, and if not, why not?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, bayesian-probability

Roughly speaking, a stick-breaking prior is a random discrete probability measure $P$ on a measurable space $\mathcal X$ of the form
$$P=\sum_{j\ge1}w_j\delta_{\theta_j}$$
where $(w_j)_{j\ge1}$ is a random sequence of positive values summing to 1 almost surely, and $(\theta_j)_{j\ge1}$ is an iid sequence independent of $(w_j)_{j\ge1}$ taking values in $\mathcal X$.

[*Roughly speaking* because definitions don't appear settled - e.g. many people impose RAM structure on $(w_j)_{j\ge1}$, some do not.]

Have stick-breaking measures for which the sequence of atoms $(\theta_j)_{j\ge1}$ is not iid been considered? I've seen one recent paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.08135 for which the atoms form a Markov chain, but I'm wondering if non-iid atoms have been considered before in a more applied context, and if not, what is the vital importance (contextually or mathematically) of using an iid sequence of atoms (beyond ease of analysis and simulation)?

---

I recently came across a paper that used non-iid atoms in building a common atoms model (https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2021.1933499) involving a modification of nested Dirichlet processes. More generally, this is an example of putting a (prior) distribution on the common distribution of the sequence $(\theta_j)_{j\ge1}$, ultimately producing non-iid atoms (though still conditionally iid given the observed common distribution). This would be a natural response to dependencies in context which we are trying to model and/or a feature of a Bayesian approach.

Still interested in the potential mathematical importance of the iid sequence, though!